# Mint OIDC ID token programmatically using a third-party service (Okta, Auth0, etc.) without having users in the service

Tags: openid-connect, auth0, okta

In my backend server, is it possible to use a third-party (3p) service (e.g., Okta, Auth0, etc.) to mint an OIDC ID token programmatically? Without having all of my users defined in the 3p service? And then this 3p also provides me with a `.well-known/openid-configuration` and `client secret` that I can give to some other app (relying party) that can then validate the OIDC ID token I minted?

**Problem**: I'm an event platform with a custom pool of users. Some of these users aren't even signed up with a password or anything; they just registered for the event with an email and name. I'm using some `product P` (relying party) embedded in my website that wants me to authenticate users via OIDC ID tokens.

- I determined that some user `U` on my website should be allowed to attend the event.
- I mint an OIDC ID token for `U`: `okta.mintIDToken({scopes: {name: 'foo', email: 'foo@bar.com'}})`
- I give `P` the minted OIDC ID token
- `P` verifies the token using the `.well-known/openid-configuration` and `client secret` I gave it
- User `U` is allowed to use the embedded product `P` in my website! Success!

**Complication**: I don't want to build a Identity Platform (IdP) from scratch, with all the public endpoints that I would have to support (`jwks_uri` `revocation_endpoint`, etc.). I tried using Okta and Auth0, but the methods I tried required me to have all of my users that I could potentially create an OIDC ID token for pre-defined in the 3p's user database, or they require the user to go through a sign-in flow on my website.

Is there a service in Okta or Auth0 that I misunderstood that actually has this functionality? If not, is there some other service that can help me with this?